# jQuery: master select box to apply values

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following select boxes:

```
<select class="actionList" name="masterBox">
<option value="0">No Action</option>
<option value="1">Move</option>
<option value="2">Terminate</option>
</select>

============================================================


<select class="actionList" name="action_ISI00222">
<option value="0">No Action</option>
<option value="1">Move</option>
<option value="2">Terminate</option>
</select>

<select class="actionList" name="action_ISI00223">
<option value="0">No Action</option>
<option value="1">Move</option>
<option value="2">Terminate</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to put a jQuery action, so that when a value is selected in the `masterBox`, it is also applied on the other select boxes.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="masterBox"]').change(function(){

$('.actionList option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr('selected','selected');

});


});
```

Comment: This is working, I have just changed the value from 'input' to 'select'. Thank you

Comment: Yes thats a typo yes it must be `select `

Answer (score 1):

You can fine a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/nhZDF/1/
please note that I added IDs to the elements